# how to check if a div has children in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i was building a blog where users can comment , and i map all of my response in a parent div, but when there is no comment i want to show users that there is no comments, in order to do that i want to to know that the parent div has any children or not. How can i achieve this?

div

```js
    function Answer({ map }) {
    const [test, settest] = useState(map);
    const [div, setdiv] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const el1 = document.querySelector('.forum_answer_main');
        setdiv(el1);
    }, []);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (div.hasChildNodes() == 0) {
            console.log('empty');
        } else {
            console.log('not empty');
        }
    }, []);

    return <div className='forum_answer_main'>{test}</div>;
}

export default Answer;
```

Comment: When working in react you should forget that DOM methods even exist and focus on the state that is used to render the DOM nodes

Comment: @charlietfl This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than checking if the parent has any children, you should check if there are any comments in your state data and decide what to display from there. All rendering decisions should be made from the data in props or state, not from the DOM.